# Combine multiple csv files with same prefix in CMD?

Tags: csv, cmd, prefix

I have a folder with several csv files. They are labeled like this:

```
Name1-year.csv
Name1-year.csv
Name2-year.csv
Name2-year.csv
Name3-year.csv
etc...
```

I know you can use `copy *.csv combined.csv` to combine all the csv files in a directory, but is there a way to combine files with the same prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```
copy prefix* copiedfile.csv
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, I meant in Unix . Congrats for copying my answer based on command prompt changing just the syntax by the way

Answer (score 0):

To filter for a certain prefix use this:

```cmd
copy "prefix*.csv" "combined.csv" /B
```

The `/B` tells `copy` to treat the destination a binary file, hence no <kbd>EOF</kbd>/<kbd>SUB</kbd> character (ASCII `0x1A`) becomes appended.